C:\Program Files\Python311 is empty
I'm pretty sure i deleted the contents of (C:\Program Files\Python311) now pyCharm doesn't work.
I already tried to reinstall python but it just reinstalls to the appdata folder. Pycharm error: No Python at '"C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe' , What do i do?

maybe go to File > Settings in PyCharm and set new path to python.exe. I'm not sure but it may have even function to autosearch all python.exe on disk.
